# OnsenUI keeps using unsafe-eval and unsafe-inline, even with the ng-csp directive

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui, content-security-policy

**EDIT :**
I've submitted the issue to their GitHub : https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/936

**EDIT 2 :** It's being taken care of ;)

(Sorry for my English, it's not my native language ;) )

This is my first question on stackoverflow. For now, I've always find that someone else have had the same problem as me, and got an answer.

But this time, I can't seem to find a solution, so either I'm the first one, or I'm missing something.

I'm developing a app for Windows Phone and Android (for now), using cordova, onsenui (so angular), and jQuery (thought I don't think this last one is causing trouble here).

I decided that I'll start using CSP the right way, to get a more secure app.

I've added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://foo.com>` in the index.html page, to start with.
I've found that angular does a lot of unsafe things, and I learned about the ngCsp directive.

So now I have :

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-csp>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://foo.com>

    <script src="lib/onsen-1.3.10/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/onsen-1.3.10/js/onsenui.js"></script>
    ...
</html>
```

I don't get anymore CSP's errors about angular.js, but I keep getting some for onsenui.js (unsafe-inlines and unsafe-evals).
For know, the only solution I've found is :

- to allow unsafe-inline in CSP
- to arrange the only line in onsenui.js that causes an unsafe-eval :

In onsenui.js, I've replaced line 4888 :

```
}(new Function("return this")()));
```

by :

```
}(function() {return this;}()));
```

So my question is : am I the only one out there having this problem ? Does someone here is using cordova, onsenui, and CSP without any problem ?
I'd rather not put 'unsafe-eval' in the CSP meta, and I'd like to remove the 'unsafe-inline'.

Sorry for this long post, and thank you for your help ! ;)